# UITableViewCell's xib acting really strange

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I'm sorry for the ambiguous title, but I just can't find the right words to describe this.

I have this xib, it contains one UITableViewCell, the UITableView has one subView(which is a simple UIView). AutoLayout is off. Both the UITableViewCell and its subView has the same width : 320. The subView's x and y are both 0.

The subView's autoResizingMask is like this:

[image: ScreenShot1]

On iPhone 6 simulator, both the UITableViewCell and its contentView's widths are 375. But the subView's width become 695.

I initialized the UITableViewCell like this:

```
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[sBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.width = kScreenWidth;
}
```

Then I did nothing to it, nor to the subView. I don't even have a IBOutlet for the subView.

When I changed the subView's autoResizing to this, the problem disappears:

[image]

On iPhone 6 simulator, the subView's width is 375 just as it should be.

Then I changed it like this:

[image]

On the simulator, the subView's width shrink to 125.5.

The strangest thing happened when I opened the xib as source code. I don't see anything wrong with it.

```
    <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="BdK-FL-moU" customClass="SProductDetailTagCell">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="BdK-FL-moU" id="BjX-yQ-6aR">
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <subviews>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="KEc-b0-BoQ">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="8"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.96078431369999995" green="0.96078431369999995" blue="0.96078431369999995" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
        </tableViewCellContentView>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="139" y="402"/>
    </tableViewCell>
```

I did't do anything to change it.

But when I opened the xib in Interface Builder again, the subView's width simply changes!

[image]

I find that it changes the same way as it changes on the simulator: when  the autoresizing is like the first screenshot, it expands. When like the second screenshot, it stays. when like the third screenshot, it shrinks.

I tried deleting the xib and create a new one, but the behaviors remain the same. It drives me crazy. Any suggestions? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the problem might be there's something wrong with my project, and the xib is created **seperately** with the cell's .h and .m file.

I fixed this problem by deleting the xib and deleting the UITableViewCell's .h and .m as well. Then I created a new subclass of UITableViewCell, checked "Also create xib file" when creating. By copying all the code back, and drawing the new xib exactly the same as the old one, the problem goes away.